# WCF + Web API - Como integrar?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, wcf

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma web api e preciso integrar com um serviço de um terceiro que é um WCF. Eu tenho a definição do WSDL, integrei na minha solution como um service reference, mas está apontando para um arquivo físico no meu PC.

Como eu integro esse código, que está apontando para um WSDL local, com o serviço hospedado em outro ambiente? Possuo a url do serviço (que não possui o WSDL habilitado ou público, pois quando adiciono a service reference, tenho um erro informando que não foi possível baixar os metadata do serviço), mas não sei como integrar com o WCF.

Se fosse uma web api, eu usaria o HttpClient para integrar, mas WCF eu não faço ideia de como fazer.

Comment: "está apontando para um arquivo físico no meu PC" Como assim? Você não colocou a URL do serviço?

Comment: Se o serviço é WCF, normalmente deve-se adicionar o sufixo `?wsdl` para exibir apenas o WSDL. Entretanto, isso tudo é informado no endereço do serviço.

Comment: Com a url do serviço, não é possível adicionar a referência. Apresenta esse erro:

`There was an error downloading 'https://***.svc/RS/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://***.svc/RS'.
Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority '***'.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.`

Comment: Acessando direto o endereço do serviço (mesmo com o ?wsdl), aparece essa mensagem: **Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.**

Answer (score 0):

pelo que entendi, você adicionou o wsdl por um arquivo local correto ? nunca fiz isso, mas quando preciso mudar a url do ws , basta defini-lá:

```
string url = "http://host.com.br/ws.asmx";
objws.Url = url;
```

onde objws é um objeto do tipo da referência que você adicionou.

Ex: [image: referência adicionada]

[wsIntegra] é o namespace do webservice que você definiu ao adicionar a referência.
[SiIntegraWebService] é a classe do webservice definida no servidor.

```
public wsIntegra.SiIntegraWebService objws = new wsIntegra.SiIntegraWebService();
```

Comment: Ok, mas o que é esse objeto _objws_? Pra um serviço WebAPI, utilizo HttpClient e consigo me comunicar. Pra WCF, eu não faço ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: editei a resposta para melhor entendimento, na hora que você adicionou o wsdl, você deu um nome a ele, que é o namespace

Comment: Acho que entendi! Vou testar aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: uma observação, é que é através desse objeto (objws) que você irá executar os métodos disponíveis no ws.